# Regex vs line by line read efficiency - general concept question

Tags: regular-expressions, efficiency

Say, I have a file that is somewhere between 10-20 pages long. I need to extract 10-20 pieces of information from it that I can fairly easily extract using a series of regex-es or by running code that reads things line by line and extract information that way. Is there a way that is necessarily faster than the other?

I know that regex are generally faster for searching things. But the uncertainty I have here is more like, if I use a regex approach, I virtually have to run regex on the text multiple times, whereas if I were reading it line by line, I would basically be only reading everything only once. I wonder if there is a general principal or maybe just some rule of thumb that one way is better than the other. Is there something like that? Or will it be so scenario dependent that I really won't know the answer without doing testing each time I have something like this?